# How to create mock object for unit testing

Tags: jquery, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

How to Write Test Cases: I'm write test cases in beginner please help.

Angular class of function.

```
picklistScroll() {
          const picklistWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('picklist-values-wrapper')[0];

           jQuery(picklistWrapper).animate({
              scrollTop: picklistWrapper.scrollHeight
          }, 'slow'); 
}
```

Below is the spec.ts file −

```
  describe('picklistScroll', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {

    // scroll height problem coming
    var dummyElement = document.createElement('div');
    dummyElement.className = "picklist-values-wrapper";
    dummyElement.style.height = '200px';
    dummyElement.style.overflowY = 'auto';

    document.getElementsByClassName = jasmine.createSpy('picklist-values-wrapper').and.returnValue(dummyElement);

    });
  });
```

fails with following message:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'scrollHeight')

Looks like I need to create mock object for innerHTML. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('picklistScroll', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
    // scroll height problem coming
    var dummyElement = document.createElement('div');
    dummyElement.className = "picklist-values-wrapper";
    dummyElement.style.height = '200px';
    dummyElement.style.overflowY = 'auto';
    
document.getElementsByClassName=jasmine.createSpy('dummyElement.scrollHeight')
    document.getElementsByClassName = jasmine.createSpy('picklist-values-wrapper').and.returnValue(dummyElement);

    });
  })
```

You need to create a spy for this as like this.

Comment: thanks for the response. But unfortunately, it doesn't work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4f9Z.png